# What type of traffic applies to "INPUT" for a "wan" zone?

Tags: openwrt, lede

I have two zones: `lan` (type: bridge) and `wan`.

I set the firewall to forward from `lan` to `wan`.

`lan` zone: INPUT:ACCEPT, OUTPUT:ACCEPT

`wan` zone: INPUT:REJECT, OUTPUT:ACCEPT

Would `INPUT` for `wan` apply to packets from just the Internet? Or does it include forwarded packets from the`lan` zone?

Answer (score 5):

The per-zone INPUT rule governs traffic coming from outside the router, hitting an IP assigned to an interface in the given zone.

The only way traffic from `lan` can get to `wan` is *through* the router, and so in that sense isn't coming from 'outside' (from the perspective of the `wan` zone).

So to answer your question - yes, `INPUT` for `wan` applies to packets from just the Internet.

---

While this isn't part of your question, it may help others: the per-zone `FORWARD` rule governs traffic *between interfaces in the **same** zone*. This is different to 'forwardings' which governs traffic *between **different** zones*.
[image]